# Am I experiencing a z-index issue or something else on this website?

Tags: html, css, joomla3.0

Hello and thanks for reading. I'm stressed out and ready to throw in the towel.

On http://www.chowderhound.com The maroon toolbar at the top is sticky, along with the main navigation under it. The problem is that the 3 links in the toolbar aren't activated until you scroll down the page and the bar becomes sticky. I have fought with this for 3 days. Can anyone assist me on making the links in the toolbar active at all times?

The links in question are in this screenshot... 
[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONuFH.jpg)

Thank you!  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Exactly: it's covered by relative divs that come after it. Just add `z-index: 10` to `.tm-toolbar`.

Comment: I just tried that and the issue still exists.  Do I need code this differently?  I'm just at a loss.

Comment: sorry, I'm wrong: you need `z-index: 1002`, because the div after it has z-index set to 1001. :)

Comment: This is what's driving me crazy.  So if I give it a 1002, then it covers the logo.  So then I give the logo a z-index of 1003 and the toolbar still covers the top of it.

Comment: Unfortunately you won't be able to put a logo over sticky nav with clean methods because it is scrollable and should go under the nav. You can simply shift the logo a bit to the bottom to prevent overlapping.

Comment: I think you're right.  I just didn't want to have to move the logo down.  Makes it look funny.  I appreciate your help.  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. You can try to move logo to nav and make it sticky as well (together with the nav), but then it will cover slight part of the page all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a test with Chrome Developer tools and it seems to have solved the issue. You will need to apply the following changes to your CSS...

`<div class="uk-sticky-placeholder">` needs to have a top margin of 30px. So after `margin: 0px;` add `margin-top: 30px;`

`<div class="tm-navbar">` needs to have a top position of 0px; so in your CSS rule `.tm-navbar, .tm-navbar.uk-active[style]` change `top: 32px !important;` to `top: 0px !important;`